# Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: onResume with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

This class definition causes an immediate runtime crash on Xamarin for Android.

```
public class BaseCompatActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
    }
}
```

The error message is:

Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: md5e8727ee9d36911e204981187fd2b13a2.BaseCompatActivity.n_onResume:()V

I have an inheritance chain that goes like this

MainActivity > DrawerActivity > BaseCompatActivity > AppCompatActivity

**If I override OnResume in MainActivity or DrawerActivity, there is no problem.** It is only if I override it in BaseCompatActivity that I get that error message.

This happens when running API level 17 in the emulator. It does not happen when running on an API level 22 device.

What could be causing this mysterious behaviour?

Comment: If you are using the beta channel, switch to the stable channel.

Comment: I don't think I'm on the beta channel. I installed it when it started shipping with Visual Studio, with the standard Visual Studio installer.